# How to download certain file using Dropbox API V2?

Tags: java, android, download, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to download certain file/folder from Dropbox using `DbxClientV2`. I know the path to this file and it will always be the same so I don't want let user to pick it. I've seen:

```
public void onFileClicked(final FileMetadata file) { }
```

But it seems this isn't what I'm looking for and I don't know how to create `FileMetadata` object using file path.
I can't find anything helpful. I've got [sample class](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/7ecc15cf0f51d6ae2ba5cdb334aac2c2f3474b87/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DownloadFileTask.java) from **GitHub** but it still requires `FileMetadata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it took me some time so I post my answer for others.

Of course you have to specify the place where you want to save it (but that's obvious) then create `OutputStream`:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM";
                File file = new File(path, "test.txt");

                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

After this we create `Metadata` object and initialize it and then download it using `metadata.getPathLower()`.

```
 try {
                    Metadata pathMetadata = client.files().getMetadata("/test.txt");
                    client.files().download(pathMetadata.getPathLower()).download(outputStream);
                    Log.e("METADATA", pathMetadata.toString());

                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The strange this is that the `getPathLower()` returns `"test.txt"` but when we type it raw inside `download()` method it returns

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String 'path' does not match pattern
```

(`"/test.txt"` doesn't work too).
It took me much time to make it work so I hope my answer helps someone to save this time.
Happy coding!

Comment: Glad to see you already got this working. For reference though, "/test.txt" should certainly work too, as that's the correct format. What did you get when you tried that? (Perhaps there was a typo?) You also shouldn't need the call to `getMetadata` anyway if you already know the path. `getPathLower` just returns a string like "/test.txt" (not "test.txt", which wouldn't work as it's missing the leading slash).